# How to extract a sequence of frames with ffmpeg and get it with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, extract, frames

Since reading single frames is kinda slow , i tried to extract multiple frames at once. Now i got the Problem that ffmpeg does not return a list but a bunch of bytes.
os : win10
python version 3.7.4
ffmpeg extracting frames from mp4

```py
        command = [self.FFMPEG_BINARY,
                   '-loglevel', 'fatal',
                   '-ss', str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=frame_index / self._fps)),
                   '-i', os.path.join(self._path, self._filename),
                   '-threads', str(self.THREAD_NUM),
                   '-vf', 'scale=%d:%d' % (self._resolution[0], self._resolution[1]),
                   '-vframes', str(num_frames),
                   '-f', 'image2pipe',
                   '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
                   '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']

        pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        tmplist = []
        for _ in range(num_frames):
            output, err = pipe.communicate()
            tmplist.append(output)
            if err: print('error', err); return None;
            pygame.image.frombuffer(output, self._resolution, "RGB")

        return tmplist
```

Expected : a list of pygame Surfaces
Got : ValueError: Buffer length does not equal format and resolution size

Comment: SOLUTION : 
raw = pipe.stdout.read(resolution[0]*resolution[1]*3)
this calcualtes the buffersize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pipe can’t return a list, just a stream. You need to use a format like yuv4mpegpupe, then parse the frames out. Or use pre-calculate the size of each frame and read that number of bytes.

For example rgb24 would be width times height time 3 bytes.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.